# Sending an email as "High Importance" via SPD Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, email

Is it possible to send an email as high importance through a SharePoint Designer Workflow?

Use case would be if a checkbox is checked, send email as high importance.  If it is not, send regular email.

Answer (score 0):

OOTB through Designer, I don't think it is possible. You can create a custom workflow to send an email with high priority.

In C#:

```
        var mailSend = new MailMessage("abc@gmail.com", "abc@gmail.com");
        mailSend.Subject = "Subject";
        mailSend.Body = "Body";
        mailSend.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        var objSmtp = new SmtpClient();
        objSmtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        objSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "password");
        objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;
        objSmtp.Send(mailSend);
```